# Meteor packages.json or package.json

Tags: meteor

A Meteor code runs fine in development. In the app folder, there is `packages.json` which looks like this:

```
{  "cheerio": "0.20.0" }
```

While uploading the app to AWS, an error about `package.json` file came up. So thinking the file name must be without "s" at the end, I used my IDE and renamed the file to `package.json`, restarted meteor, only to notice that both of them are present, so I deleted packages.json and restarted the app by running `meteor` from the terminal, where I get:

> creating `packages.json` for the first time

Which one is needed and what to do from here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`packages.json` in the application root contains the npm packages. This file is created when you create the package. The dependencies are then loaded into the `node-modules` folder.

In the [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html)

> npm packages are configured in a `package.json` file at the root of your project. If you create a new Meteor project, you will have such a file created for you. If not you can run `meteor npm init` to create one.

The meteor packages (the ones you install using `meteor add` are located in the `.meteor/packages.json`

So, both files are for different purpose and are independent of each other.

Since, you were getting error with package.json and you haven't shared, I guess this was related to version control. 
Please run the following commands :

`meteor npm install`
`meteor npm install --save meteor-node-stubs` , if upgrading from pre 1.3 version.

Please share the exact error message. This will help in better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I opened [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39430934/5047454) for a different error now.