# Uploading Meteor up to AWS E.Beanstalk Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor

A Meteor project being uploaded to AWS Elastic Beanstalks using the AWS console. The content of the root folder including the hidden files and folders without `.git` and `.idea` are being zipped and that `zipped.zip` file was uploaded.

The content of the `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "Appname2",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

The beanStalk console is reporting Error:

> No start scripts located in package.json. Node.js may have issues starting. Add start scripts or place code in a file named server.js or app.js.

Meteor version 1.4.1.1 which uses nodejs 5.5.0
AWS node versin is: 5.12.0

How can this be fixed so the error goes away? Thanks

Comment: did you try rebuilding the npm packages on the server?

Comment: @Ankit No, How can I do that? thx

Comment: Use command 'meteor npm rebuild'